# Ionic DateTime field, Rails API and Timezones

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ionic-framework

I am developing a Ionic 3 app with a Rails Backend API. My Postgres database is set to UTC and the default Rails app timezone is 'America/Sao_Paulo.

In my Ionic App I have a DateTime field:

```
<ion-datetime displayFormat="DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm" [(ngModel)]="scheduled_at"></ion-datetime>
```

The value is send to my API where it is stored to the database. The issue is now that usually I would expect that Rails converts the DateTime from Sao_Paulo to UTC to store it in the database. But what happens is that it stores it as it is and thinks it already is UTC.

In my create method I tried to use:

```
Time.use_zone('America/Sao_Paulo') do
      ride.scheduled_at = Time.zone.parse(params[:scheduled_at])
end
```

But it still stores the original params DateTime as it is to the database.

Any ideas?

Comment: I have been digging into this one and seeing some unexpected behavior as well.  When you first click the ion-datetime control without a value, does it populate the selectors with the UTC time?  For example, the time here is `6/16/2018, 5:57:15 PM`, but the selections default to 22 hours 57 minutes because that is the UTC time `2018-06-16T22:57:15.047Z`.  Once you confirm this is the behavior you are seeing as well, we can work on the best solution.

Comment: Yes, that's what happened. I have solved it by adding this simple line of code: scheduled_at: String = moment().format();